# Azure multiple WebRoles at 80 port in one Cloud Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have project with one Web Role (ASP.NET MVC).
Not i want to divide it into 2 WebRoles: Web and WebAPI. I want host it in same cloud service, but i don't want to assign 8080 port to my WebAPI WebRole.
I want to use mysite.com and api.mysite.com in one cloud service project and deploy it as single unit.
It is possible to solve this only by hostHeader in Binding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have multiple WebRoles binding to the same endpoint (port). But you can have multiple Web Sites (Web Applications) in the same Web Role on Azure. Thus, having multiple web project all on the same port 80 with different host headers.

Here are some startup guidances:

- [Configure Web Role for multiple Web Sites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg433110.aspx)
- [Tips for publishing multiple sites to a web role](http://michaelcollier.wordpress.com/2013/01/14/multiple-sites-in-a-web-role/)
- [Running multiple web sites in a single web role](http://blog.elastacloud.com/2011/01/11/azure-running-multiple-web-sites-in-a-single-webrole/)